# Storage of new data in an ongoing QGIS/QField project

Tags: qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

In a hypothetical situation, I:

1. create a QGIS project on my desktop in QGIS in a standard documents>QGIS folder location.
2. then package for Qfield and a copy? is created under User>Qfield>cloud>projectname.

In a future scenario this synced and opened in the field and reuplaoded to the Qfield cloud.

My question is should any changes made to the project on the desktop all be stored in the user>qfield>cloud directory?

Should I effectively try and ignore the original folder directory in my documents that was made to set up the project?

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to make a comment. I am currently exploring the QField/QGIS avenue to update/retrieve data by our personnel in the field. We have in excess of 3k items that have to be inspected mostly annually or when some issue is reported to us. We are unlikely to use the cloud, though it looks like your same issue of original folder data being present is similar. So our context:
1. data is drawn from a db in a .shp format into a project
2. Personal, via Android/QField, update a limited field set
3. Updated field set updates the db
4. Reports sent relevant managers I a